# How to synchronize live video streams from two network cameras?

Tags: node.js, live-streaming, rtp, ip-camera, onvif

I've [two network cameras](http://www.cpplusworld.com/cp-unc-cs10l1) that support RTSP, ONVIF v2.0, and a few other protocols (full list is in the link above). I want to read frames from these two streams at the same instance (or at least within a few ms) so that I can get a better view of my place by combining the information from these two images as if I were using a stereo camera pair and adding some intelligence on top of it.

So far, I've looked into RTSP and found that the RTP packet Header has this information ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol#wikitable)) and I found that I can use [the NTP timestamp from RTCP sender reports](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/rtp/faq.html#timestamp-initial) but I'm not really sure how to use these to get absolute timestamps per frame. I'm using nodejs ([rtsp-ffmpeg library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtsp-ffmpeg)) to retrieve frames from rtsp stream, I can use ONVIF but I didn't find any clear way to get the timestamp per frame or synchronize the videos to make sure I read the frames for same client timestamp with ONVIF either ([ONVIF v2.6 Specs](https://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v260.pdf)).

Comment: Two separate cameras that are not genlocked (synchronized from the same frame clock) are not going to create frames at the same time and have no hope of truly being in-sync.  Even in ideal conditions, the cameras are going to drift from each other over time.  The best thing you can do in this case is to have a recording device as close to the source as possible (on the same network) and treat every frame you get as live.  Then, when you have a frame received from each camera, treat it as the current frame.

Comment: What Brad said. But if you wanna try something else - the RTP Headers have timestamps. They'll start at random numbers for each elementary streams and increase according to the clock rate of your stream. You can estimate with something like this - first RTP packet comes in with TS=1234, some time later a RTP packet comes in with TS=91234 - it is to be displayed at time 91234-1234/90000=1.0seconds (assuming 90khz clock rate for the stream). I'm skipping a lot of caveats. Look for the marker bits in the rtp headers. Search RFC specs for RTP Payload format of whatever codec your'e using. goodluck